# Difference between file:/// and file://///%3F/

Tags: javascript, python, html, browser, filesystems

I made a webscraper using python and a auto .html writter to represent the downloaded data, and the files are saved in folders based on the page title.
In the .html, an anchor tag was `<a href="(C92) [Kuragamo (Tukinowagamo)] Tonari no Chinatsu-chan R - Next Door's Chinatsu-chan R [English] [Team Koinaka]/(C92) [Kuragamo (Tukinowagamo)] Tonari no Chinatsu-chan R - Next Door's Chinatsu-chan R [English] [Team Koinaka].html" class="list_class">(C92) [Kuragamo (Tukinowagamo)] Tonari no Chinatsu-chan R - Next Door's Chinatsu-chan R [English] [Team Koinaka]</a>`
As you see it's a relative link in my Windows system.

Whenever i click to the anchor point, it opens this link
`file:///E:/Random%20Codes/C/Python/Test/Web%20ripper%202/Web-leach/Download_Projects/RA%20RA%201.1/(C92)%20[Kuragamo%20(Tukinowagamo)]%20Tonari%20no%20Chinatsu-chan%20R%20-%20Next%20Door's%20Chinatsu-chan%20R%20[English]%20[Team%20Koinaka]/(C92)%20[Kuragamo%20(Tukinowagamo)]%20Tonari%20no%20Chinatsu-chan%20R%20-%20Next%20Door's%20Chinatsu-chan%20R%20[English]%20[Team%20Koinaka].html`
and shows that the link is unavailable and asks me to check the link.

However I tried to open it through file manager and it opens the file with this link:
`file://///%3F/E:/Random%20Codes/C/Python/Test/Web%20ripper%202/Web-leach/Download_Projects/RA%20RA%201/(C94)%20[Kuragamo%20(Tukinowagamo)]%20Tonari%20no%20Chinatsu-chan%20R%2003%20-%20Next%20Door's%20Chinatsu-chan%20R%2003%20[English]%20[Team%20Koinaka]/(C94)%20[Kuragamo%20(Tukinowagamo)]%20Tonari%20no%20Chinatsu-chan%20R%2003%20-%20Next%20Door's%20Chinatsu-chan%20R%2003%20[English]%20[Team%20Koinaka].html`

The only difference I could find was `file:///` and `file://///%3F/` at the beginning and I replaced `file:///` with `file://///%3F/E` in the html file and it worked absolutely fine.
Tested on other files and found only some works with `file:///` and all works with  `file://///%3F/`

***So when should I tell the anchor to open starting with `file://///%3F/E` or `file:///`***
sorry the links are too big but i think they are important.

Comment: For some reason, the encoded URL is getting re-encoded. Ultimately, it doesn't matter, because the browser decodes it as many times as needed to get the final url in string format.

Comment: but after the encoding and decoding stuffs, the browser can't send me from on page to another. everytime i need to open such files, i need to open it through filemanager... Trying with local host and see if anything changes

Comment: on local host files works fine, but not when the html (with the anchor) was opened with filemanager